# how to join two model of two separated database python peewee

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I'm using peewee to use Mysql database.

```
import peewee
db_1 = peewee.MySQLDatabase('db_1', **{'user': 'root'})
db_2 = peewee.MySQLDatabase('db_2', **{'user': 'root'})

class User(peewee.Model):
    id = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    username = peewee.CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db_1

class Tweet(peewee.Model):
    id = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    tweet = peewee.CharField()
    user = peewee.IntegerField(db_column='user_id')

    class Meta:
        database = db_2
```

I want to execute this code:

```
m = Tweet().select(Tweet, User).join(
    User, join_type=JOIN_INNER, on=User.id == Tweet.user
).where(
    User.id == 13
)
```

but it raises this error:

```
peewee.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'db_2.user' doesn't exist")
```

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinkbest solution for problem use `view` on second database.
I create a views of `users` into `db_2` and that code is work.

Comment: Peewee does not have any built-in helpers for joining across multiple databases. I'm glad that you were able to accomplish what you needed using a view, however!

Comment: @coleifer is this `view` part of peewee's API?  I'm trying to get something useful from this answer but I can't find any sort of `view` in peewee's docs.